# Add auto complete to dropdown list macro

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to add auto complete to this Macro so that when a usue starts typing in a cell in column A it auto complets

Thank you

```
Sub CreateDV()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Sheets("New").Select
Set ws = Sheets("New")

   lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

  Set rng = Range("A4:A" & lRow)

With rng.Validation
   For Each cell In rng
     .Delete
     .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
     xlBetween, Formula1:="Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday"
     .IgnoreBlank = True
     .InCellDropdown = True
     .InputTitle = ""
     .ErrorTitle = ""
     .InputMessage = ""
     .ErrorMessage = ""
     .ShowInput = True
     .ShowError = True
   Next cell
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried the solution @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961201/auto-complete-text-box-in-excel-vba ?

Comment: John thanks for the heads up I will take a look at it